# Lista encadeada - função remove

Tags: c, lista

Estou programando uma lista encadeada sem cabeça, nesse programa existe uma função remove que tem como objetivo eliminar todos os inteiros repetidos numa lista, px: tomando os valores 8 2 8 3 8 a função tem que devolver 2 3, porém essa função aparentemente entrou em loop, pois a execução não termina, não aparecendo runtime e não a erros ou warnings na compilação. segue código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct reg {
      int conteudo;
      struct reg *prox;
};
typedef struct reg celula;

void insere (celula **p, int x) {
      celula *novo, *q;
       q = *p;

      novo = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
      novo->conteudo = x;

      if (*p == NULL) {
            novo->prox = NULL;
            *p = novo;
      }

      else {
             while (q->prox != NULL)
                    q = q->prox;

      novo->prox = q->prox;
      q->prox = novo;
      }
}

celula* Remove (celula *p, int x) {
       celula *aq, *q, *aux;
       aq = NULL;
       aux = q = p;

       while (aux != NULL) {

             while (q->prox != NULL && q->conteudo != x) {
                   aq = q;
                   q = q->prox;
             }

             if (aq == NULL) p = q->prox;

             else aq->prox = q->prox;
             free(q);
             aux = aux->prox;
         }
      return q;
}

void imprime (celula *p) {
      celula *q;

      if (p == NULL) printf ("Lista Vazia");

      for (q = p; q != NULL; q = q->prox)
               printf ("%d ", q->conteudo);
      printf("\n");
}

int main() {
      celula *lista = NULL;
      celula *lst = NULL;

      insere(&lista, 8);
      insere(&lista, 2);
      insere(&lista, 8);
      insere(&lista, 3);
      insere(&lista, 8);
      imprime(lista);
      lst = Remove(lista, 8);

      imprime(lst);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `Remove` está entrando em *looping* porque após a primeira iteração, o valor do ponteiro `q` se "perde".

Há mais 2 problemas nessa função, segue o código abaixo com os problemas comentados:

```
celula* Remove (celula *p, int x) {
       celula *aq, *q, *aux;
       aq = NULL;
       aux = q = p;

       while (aux != NULL)
       {
           // q tem que ser inicializado com o valor aux aqui
           q = aux;
           while (q->prox != NULL && q->conteudo != x) {
               aq = q;
               q = q->prox;
           }

           if (aq == NULL) p = q->prox;
           else aq->prox = q->prox;

           // Como aux pode ter o mesmo valor de q
           // a atualização tem que vir antes do
           // free
           aux = aux->prox;
           free(q);
        }
    // aqui, tem que retornar p e não q
    return p;
}
```

Após a execução:

```
8 2 8 3 8
2 3
```

---

**EDIT:**
Segue um exemplo comentado de uma forma diferente de implementar esta função, com apenas um *looping*:

```
celula* Remove2(celula *p, int x) {
    celula *atual, *anterior;

    atual = p;

    // Lista vazia. Retorna
    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;    

    anterior = NULL;
    while (atual)
    {        
        if (atual->conteudo == x)
        {

            if (anterior == NULL)                
            {
                //
                // --| Remove um elemento do início da lista |--                    
                //
                p = p->prox; // Atualiza o início da lista
                free(atual);
                atual = p;
                continue;                
            } else 
            {
                //
                // --| Remove um elemento do meio ou final da lista |--
                //
                anterior->prox = atual->prox;
                free(atual);                    
                atual = anterior; // continua a partir do elemento anterior
                continue;
            };
        };
        // Caminha para o próximo elemento
        anterior = atual;
        atual = atual->prox;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Abaixo, os testes da função `Remove2`:

```
Remove o 8:
8 8 8 8 8 8 2 8 3 8 8 2 8 3 4 8 8 
2 3 2 3 4 

Remove o 2:
8 8 8 8 8 8 2 8 3 8 8 2 8 3 4 8 8 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 3 8 8 8 3 4 8 8 

Remove o 4:
8 8 8 8 8 4 8 2 8 3 8 8 2 8 3 4 8 8 4 
8 8 8 8 8 8 2 8 3 8 8 2 8 3 8 8 

Remove o 9:
9 8 8 8 8 4 8 2 9 3 8 8 2 8 3 4 8 8 9 
8 8 8 8 4 8 2 3 8 8 2 8 3 4 8 8
```

Comment: Sua s solução bem coerente, o problema é que ela ignora o ultimo ponteiro, p.ex, qdo peço a exclusão do elemento 2, ocorre o seguinte: entrada: 8 2 8 3 8, saida: 8 8 3, tentei modificar os ponteiro para resolver esta questão , mas não consegui.

Comment: Quando você atribuí `aq->prox = q->prox` no comando `else`, ele "mata" o último elemento da lista, pois `q->prox` é nulo no último elemento, e ele atribuí esse nulo ao `aq` (que é o elemento anterior/atual) :)

Comment: Esta resposta soluciona o problema da pergunta *"essa função aparentemente entrou em loop"*, porém, existem outros problemas com ponteiros (e algoritmo) no código

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo comentado, com uma forma diferente de implementar a função. Espero que ajude :)

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o erro esta em seu while, pois no caso você esta mandando 8, porem fazendo um teste de mesa percebe que na primeira interação do while ele não entra e passa direto.

Ex:
q->prox != NULL TRUE
q->conteudo != x FALSE pq 8 == 8

talvez isso resolva não consegui testar

```
 while (q->prox != NULL ) {
     if(q->conteudo != x){
         aq = q;
     }
     q = q->prox;
 }
```

Comment: Se vc refere ao laço interno -  while (q->prox != NULL && q->conteudo != x) - acredito que ele está correto, pois como ele tem que sair do laço mesmo, pois o 8 é o primeiro a ser excluido, passando para remoção na condição - if (aq == NULL) p = q->prox; - pois este é o primeiro membro da lista sem cabeça. se for o laço com aux não entendi